# My claim was accepted on MtGox.com - how do I get the cash out?

Tags: mtgox

My claim was accepted on MtGox.com - how do I get the cash out?

It lists a Yen figure but it's totally unclear what to do next.

Is it too late to transfer to Kraken and get bitcoin back?

How can I do this, can't find anything online - only options are to view, change password and transfer the amount to another person?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All information is provided on https://www.mtgox.com/. As you can see, this is going very slow, the latest update was on 8th March and the next update should come after 27th September.

If you read the latest report, you can see that the secured assets are lowering in time (most likely due to payments for investigations and cost of the bankruptcy processing). You can also see that there is a huge gap between assets + bitcoins and liabilities, which means that even if payout was going to happen today, you would get just a fraction of your claim.

The case will likely take many more months (years?) before the payouts are going to happen. And then you should not expect much to get back.